# Will interviewers still ask me behavioral questions if I have no work experience?

Tags: interviewing

I'm a recent graduate with *zero work experience*. No extracurricular activities and no part-time jobs.

Considering that this shows on my resume, **will employers still expect me to be able to answer behavioral questions**? Or won't they ask me those questions if I have no work experience to draw on for answers?

Comment: Most probably "YES". Otherwise, how can they measure you up and see if you are a good fit for the team. Behavioral questions, doesn't have to be workplace related as you know

Comment: Yes, even more so, as they don't have experience to go by, ALL they have is those behavioral questions to ask you.

Comment: For the record, when they ask you behavioral questions, it's a good idea to know the correct answer to them - not just because you need to get through the interview, but because those kinds of scenarios happen all the time and as a professional you really need to know how to handle them.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes here. This question is fairly straightforward and answerable, yet it currently has 4 close votes.

Comment: 3. I retracted mine. I don't remember voting it and I try to be careful about reading it. My bad.

Comment: @enderland to me it's quite unclear what makes asker doubt that employers will ask. Question could probably benefit of [edit] explaining this

Comment: @Lilienthal Yes, that was my question.

Comment: @Student Thanks for confirming. I've edited your post and retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, they almost assuredly will.

Large companies have standardized processes to follow for this sort of thing. They aren't going to "dumb down" the interview process for a candidate without any job experience. If they do, it's likely not going to reflect positively on you regardless.

Presumably you have coursework experience. Or had some level of working with others during your degree. When I was in school and interviewing, some of my best answers came from my "fun" I had on various projects.

Given your inexperience with work/interviewing, I would strongly recommend you take some time and research behavioral questions online. Spend time considering how to answer from your school studies.

Unless you are brilliant, the huge lack of work is likely to make interviewers less excited about you as a candidate - particularly if you do not have good answers to behavioral questions.

Answer (score 3):

They will still ask them.

In my first job out of university, despite having previous work experience, I answered some behavioural questions by explaining some things I did while in education. You don't have to give answers from previous jobs.

I suggest looking up typical behavioural question and coming up with answers to them based on what ever experience you have had while in education so you are prepared for them.

Answer (score 3):

By "behavioral questions" I assume that you mean strengths, weaknesses, etc.  They will almost certainly ask those questions and you should have answers ready for them.

When you come up with answers look at your education as the job you have had for the last however many years.  You havent worked as part of a team, but I bet at some point you worked on a group project.  Never had a demanding boss, was there ever a professor who you had to struggle to provide what they were looking for?

I would review the questions that frequently come up in a initial interview and come up with answers that fit, and be prepared to talk about how happy you are to get into the work force.  Good Luck.

Comment: Behavioral questions refers to asking questions about specific past experiences. "Tell me about a time when you had conflict within a team. How did you handle it?" or "Tell me about a time you failed. How did you deal with it?" The idea being that the candidate has to get specific and talk about what they've actually done. As opposed to "How would you deal with conflict in a team?" Now the candidate can talk about what they should do as opposed to what they have done, and what they did in the past is more representative of future results than their take on what the perfect response should be.